# How to debug or enable logging in a function

Tags: magento2.4, debugging, logging

Is there a way to enable logging, and or debug this function in Magento?
The invoices is created successfully, but the capture online doesn't work.

```
private function createInvoice(Order $order, int $capture, int $notifyCustomer, Phrase $comment): OrderInvoice
    {
        $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
        if (!$invoice) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Can not save the invoice right now.'));
        }
        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('You can not create an invoice without products.'));
        }
        $comment = $comment->render();
        $invoice->addComment($comment, $notifyCustomer);
        $invoice->setCustomerNote($comment);
        switch ($capture) {
            case OrderInvoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE:
                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(OrderInvoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
                break;
            case OrderInvoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE:
                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(OrderInvoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                break;
        }
        $invoice->register();
        $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify($notifyCustomer);
        $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        $saveTransaction = $this->transactionFactory->create();
        $saveTransaction->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $saveTransaction->save();
        return $invoice;
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **debugger** tools that is best for the Magento Debugging or you can log in this way :

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/testing.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Test the log');
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install your docker you might have something like this :

```
apt install -y \
    php${PHP_VER}-fpm \
    php${PHP_VER}-cli \
    php${PHP_VER}-bcmath \
    php${PHP_VER}-curl \
    php${PHP_VER}-gd \
    php${PHP_VER}-intl \
    php${PHP_VER}-mbstring \
    php${PHP_VER}-mysql \
    php${PHP_VER}-soap \
    php${PHP_VER}-xml \
    php${PHP_VER}-zip \
    php${PHP_VER}-xdebug

# Disable xdebug by default
RUN phpdismod xdebug
```

You can delete the disable of xdebug. Or just add the extension to php if you don't have it yet.

This should allow you to setup wdebug with your IDE.

That being said debugging with log files like @Rana Zain answer is what i'm used to do cause xdebug won't work on your deployed environements.